# Generating list of generated sources (a la foreach) in automake

Tags: makefile, autotools, automake

I am currently working on a project using templates quite extensively, and running into memory constraints during instantiation. I have split up the instantiation into a number of very simple files, which are all three-liners consisting of includes only.

I let these be generated by a rule in Makefile.am. Now I have a quite long list of files that should be generated in my Makefile, and would like to refactor this list with a foreach-like expression. In more specific terms: I have a line like

```
libfoo_la_SOURCES = a_0.cpp a_1.cpp ... b_0.cpp b_1.cpp ... c_0.cpp c_1.cpp ...
```

which could be more concisely expressed as

```
libfoo_la_SOURCES = $(foreach i,a b ...,$(foreach j,0 1 ...,$i_$j.cpp))
```

However, the second construct is not only warned against by automake, but also does not work: The files given in this manner are neither compiled nor cleaned.

My current workaround is generating this file list by a shell script.

Any ideas how to implement this iteration?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would forget about making loops: the GNU extension is not standard, and not understood by Automake.  One standard (and portable) `make` construction you can use here is the [macro expansion with substitution](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/make.html#tag_04_84_13_04):  `$(var:subst1=subst2)` will expand to the value of `$(var)` after replacing any suffix `subst1` of a word by `subst2`.  Automake understands this.

If `subst1` is empty, as in `$(var:=subst2)`, you are appending `subst2` to all files in `$(var)`.  You can use this to construct your list of files as follows:

```
f = a b c d e f
g = $(f:=_0) $(f:=_1) $(f:=_2) $(f:=_3)
all_files = $(g:=.cpp)

echo:
        @echo $(all_files)
```

Running `make echo` with the above `Makefile` will display all files from `a_0.cpp` to `f_3.cpp`.

Comment: Thanks, worked splendidly and reduced 115 lines of Makefile generated by 10 lines of sh to 20 lines of portable make.

Answer (score 2):

Like you, I discovered that the GNU make foreach function will not work like this because
the sources need to be there at the time the Makefile is generated.  So, I use [GNU Autogen](http://www.gnu.org/s/autogen/) (also [here](http://autogen.sourceforge.net/)) to generate a makefile fragment which is subsequently included in Makefile.am.  So it's probably not that different than your shell script approach.